# I Have Upload Images for C# but I want It Activate WebCam and Capture Instead of Upload

Tags: c#

I'm novice in C#. I want to have capture image using webcam instead of upload image function. Here's my codes for Upload Image.

Note:

```
"MyQuery" is my class name. Then conn is my connection declared inside my "MyQuery" class name.
```

Here's my Upload Image when the button is trigger

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    MyQuery capture = new MyQuery();
        capture.Connection();
        OpenFileDialog fp = new OpenFileDialog();
        fp.InitialDirectory = @"";
        fp.Filter = "[JPG,JPEG]|*.jpg";
        if (fp.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            this.pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(fp.FileName);
            this.pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
            this.pictureBox1.Refresh();
        }
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("Insert into MyImage (ImgFiled) values('" + this.pictureBox1.Image + "')",capture.conn);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("Successfully Uploaded");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just make path save and I solve the problem. I didn't use this code also.